# Has anyone patented a way to implement fast tunable optical filters with 1 to 2 nm bandwidth FWHM that are insensitive to angle of incidence?

Tags: software, optical-systems, us6901178

In reference to the patent: [US6901178](https://www.google.com/patents/US6901178), Fast Tunable Optical Filter

I am interested in whether the combination of a spectrometer and a tunable notch filter based on U.S Patent 6901178 with notch frequencies at any of  the visible which have nanosecond response times could be used to reduce the intensity of coherent laser beams aimed at airplane windows by 20 db while preserving the incoherent light background. The purpose of the spectrometer is to detect the wavelength(lambda) of the incoming laser beam and then tune the optical notch filter to any notch wavelength in the visible light region.
 Narrow bandwidth laser line filters exist, but they are neither switchable nor tunable.  And their performance will depend critically on the angle of incidence, and you have no control over this in the wild.
   Has anyone thought of a way  to implement fast tunable optical filters with 1 to 2 nm bandwidth FWHM that are insensitive to angle of incidence?

Comment: I think your question as it currently stands is off-topic, as it relates to technology or production. However, if your question were related to whether such an apparatus were covered by US 6901178, I think that would be on-topic and answerable.

Comment: @Maca, My question is now a prior art question. I am looking for such apparutus covered by US 6901178 and its successors. Thank you.

Comment: Has anyone patented a tunable graphene optics filter? Thank you.